# How to combine two tables data in one result set?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on one requirement, where I need to extract data from two tables (both are having diff column names), but output from both tables need to be mapped same single output schema.

For example

```
Table one
t1,t2,t3

Table two
c1,c2,c3
```

Want to run this type of query

```
select t1 as o1, t2 as o2, t3 as o3 from one
union all
select c1 as o1, c2 as o2, c3 as o3 from two
```

How can use this query in spring boot to get data from db (mysql) and map it to final data structure to use it further ? any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

If your table has `no relation with each` other or not have `common column name` fields then you can't perform `union` query.

What you have to do is, you can perform two different query then map the data to a `DTO` model. Check out this [blog resource](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables).

Comment: @OxanaGrey  did you try this solution and whats the status now?